# System.StackOverflowException in automatically generated file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm making a form in c# visual studio, and the Designer.cs gives an error.

```
 this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(409, 528); //Gives System.StackOverflowException error
```

I didn't have any problems with this until now, when I wrote this code.

```
            operation = '÷';
            if (operand1 == "")
            {
                operand1 = input;
                input = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                operand1 = calculate(operand1,input,operation);
                input = string.Empty;
            }
```

(Pretty sure that this has absolutely nothing to do with the error)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtBts.png)

Comment: Have a look at the call stack when the exception occurs

Comment: From this code alone, there is no problem in my test.

I hope you could provide more details in your question.(For example, the content in the picture in the view.)

For example: under what version (.Net 6.0?) did you create a what project (Winform?)?

Provide more code so we can reproduce your problem.